# Database multiple possible foreign key

Tags: sql, database

This is my users table.

[image]

User can either be a normal user or an author. There's really no difference aside from the fact that an author has published/posted a story.

There's also no difference to access/privilege levels as a normal user can access a story via profile and an author can access a story via profile and via dashboard. Dashboard is accessed from the user profile where it is listed in the published story as an action.(title - link to story profile, action[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRCyS.png) dashboard - link to story dashboard, action[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4ecM.png) delete)

So far so good.

The problem i encounter now is that, i have to add a review and notification system.

A user can review a story and an author. So long as a user has published at least 1 story he is considered an author.

A user receives notifications from bookmarked story updates(new chapter, any changes to the story(edit)).

If a user is an author, the user can receive notification if another user reviewed/rated his/her story and his/her profile.

I have encountered trying various ways to apply the above functions(i applied them successfully but the db designs are very bad - i also did not enforce any foreign key constraints on my database).

I am confused how to identify whether a review is for a story or an author.

[image]

If the review is for an author, how do i reference two foreign keys of user_id from the same table?(1 is the author, the other is the user who reviewed the author). -- writing to here, i think its inevitable i should separate the user table into two as normal and author. But the users table is still the same for an author and a normal user.

if the review is for a story, Do i add a story_id column to the review table and leave it null if the review is for an author and vice versa?

So i'll have author_id(fk) and story_id(fk) and one has to be null if the other has a value.(to distinguish if story or author review).

I also forgot to add, there's another table named user_profile that has a foreign key(user_id from user table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of your tables in terms of real world things and the design will be most of the way there in my experience. You have users, which can access your website, so you'll need a Users table. You have authors, who can write content, so you'll need an Authors table. All of your authors are *also* users, so you'll want a relationship there. You *DO NOT* want to have your users spread across multiple tables when it comes to security (i.e., a distinct Authors and Users table that don't overlap). That would be a nightmare to maintain. A user writes something and now you suddenly need to move all of their data to the Authors table if you go that route.

Now, for your next issue, is a review of an author and a review of a book the same thing? No, they're two distinct things, so create two tables - one for each.

```
Users
-----
user_id
username
password
...

Authors
-------
user_id
...

AuthorReviews
-------------
user_id (FK to Users table for the user who made the review)
author_id (FK to Authors table for the author that the review is about)
rating
summary
date_added

BookReviews
-----------
user_id (FK to Users table for the user who made the review)
book_id (FK to a Books table)
rating
summary
date_added
```

For the `AuthorReviews` and `BookReviews` tables the primary key would simply be composite PKs on `user_id/author_id` and `user_id/book_id` assuming that a user can only review something once.

The `user_id` might be an autoincrementing ID or some other ID that you come up with, but the `author_id` would come from the `Users` table when the author row is created. It would be a PK in both tables. Note that this only works if authors *MUST* also be users. If you can have an author who is not a user then you'll need to adjust the model so that the `author_id` is also generated and then there is a linking table between `Users` and `Authors` to make the relationship there when it's needed.

At least this is where I would start with things.

BTW, you can easily have multiple foreign keys to the same table. Just give the columns different names in the child table, but they link back to the same column in the parent.

Comment: That was my first solution. i mostly go with gut feeling. The first Database i designed was normalized and i still remember that and i use it subconsciously as a reference, idk why i insisted having only 1 table for this.(i tried something out of my comfort zone).

Also i read, that if 2 tables have the same row they should be one. Thats why i did not separate the user table into normal user and author since if a user has published a story i just foreign key the userid to the story table also since there's really no technical difference between the two aside from one having a story.

Comment: Btw, how would the author table look like? 

Author_id(PK - from user_id) 

then is that it? i really cant think of any columns that i need to add inside the author table.

Comment: If there is really nothing additional for an author then you could just have a flag to indicate that it's an author in your Users table, or alternatively if what makes them an author is having a book then you don't need to do anything. If you want to see if someone is an author then just see if they have a book.

Comment: One thing to make clear though... the Authors table as I have it above there isn't separating out the Authors from the Users - it's closer to subclassing where the Authors row has *additional* data for a user. All of their user data stays in the Users table.

Comment: So in my author_review table. 

User_id(fk to user.user_id)
and Author_id(fk to user.user_id)?

Like your last statement, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can have two different columns in a table both linking back via an FK to the same table. A perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Comment: In my project, i want to make 1 function in checking whether this user has already reviewed this(story or author) and inserting the review content.

Since my user_id and story_id are both Auto-Increment meaning there's a 100% chance that both could be the same.

Say user_id = 3 reviewd story_id = 5 and author_id = 5. 

so in both tables it would look the same 3-5 and 3-5. It would cause me problems if i tried checking if this user has already reviewed user_id = 5 and i checked both tables and author returned false but story_id = 5 returned true.

Comment: That is if i wrote a reusable method for checking reviews to call for both author and story review checks. 

Unless i make a single review table with review_id, user_id, author_id, story_id. If its a review for author then author_id will have value but story_id will be null and vice versa. Could also add a type column that links to review_type table with columns type_id and type_name 1 - author 2 - story 3 - chapter.

Comment: But idk if it's worth it? or should i just stick to making 2 separate methods to check both tables(author revview and story review).

Comment: I personally would just have two separate methods

Comment: But i've read online to keep methods reusable? 

In terms of php coding, i can say i am experienced but in terms of the concepts and ideas i am atmost at entry level.

Am i getting ahead of myself trying to opt for reusable methods?